# Replace Javascript button to Lightning Component

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am new to salesforce and trying to reproduce the button we have in the SF Classic in to Lightning. The button (Pass to Customer Service) assigns the cases to the Owner (Customer Services whose id is(eg: 00GU0000001eW6XYZA') on click of a button in the Classic. I have been reading about the quick action and take ownership button on Lightning but they makes the users Select/assign the owner to the record selected. But what I am trying to do is onclick of the button it should directly assign the record to the ownerID specified. How can I do it.

```
var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case");
caseObj.Id = '{!Case.Id}';
caseObj.OwnerId = '00GU0000001eW6XYZA';
var result2 = sforce.connection.update([caseObj]);
if (result2[0].success=='true') {
location.reload(true);}
else{alert(result2[0].errors);}
```

I tried implementing this as Lightning Component in Quick Action like below

Component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" controller="ChangeOwnerClass" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
 doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var caseId = component.get("v.recordId");
        var action = component.get("c.changeOwnerMethod");
        action.setParams({
            caseId : caseId
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            if(response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log("Case Owner Changed To Domestic Customer Service");
             }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
 }
})
```

And the class

```
public class ChangeOwnerClass {
@AuraEnabled
    public static Case changeOwnerMethod(Id caseId) {
        if(caseId != null) {
           Case c = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseId];
         c.OwnerId =  '00GU0000001eW6XYZA';
            update c;
            return c;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I added the component as a Quick Action added it in to the Layout. The issue is this doesnt appear as a button, instead it shows in the Feed

[image]

Can anyone please guide me how to move forward, I tried something and I need some help.

Comment: What you're seeing is correct. Cases that have chatter feed enabled display the quick action in the chatter publisher. See [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225871/quick-action-removal-from-chatter) for more information

Comment: @TemporaryFix Can you recommend a work around for this. I am looking for a work around without having the feed disabled

Comment: there really isn't one. the only alternative is to make a separate component and put it on the lightning layout/flexipage(not as a quick action). You could make the component more robust by adding some options users can use to pick which user to assign it to, or add some more functionality.

Comment: @TemporaryFix Do you recommend if there is any article that I can follow for this kind of things. I am new to salesforce and trying to learn

Comment: I would check [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-lightning-web-components) out